# Load/access xml file in the iFrame w/o downloading it

Tags: xml, iframe

I have a very simple iFrame with src attribute pointing directly to an xml file hosted on a different server (I don't have access to it). When page is loaded it automatically triggers downloading of this xml file. 
Is there any way to **prevent** this automatic download?

I don't need to render/view content of the xml file in iFrame, simply trying to access it and check if network allows me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the load of the page issue an ajax request and check if the XML is accessible and if yes then do what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to PREVENT auto downloading rather than changing the existing logic? The tool is already working, but this auto download is annoying.

Comment: No. It is similar to how a browser automatically downloads images on a web page. They are inline first level resources which are downloaded automatically. The solution would be to issue a dynamic request based on an event like on click of a button, or on other mouse events on demand.